# How to change the displayed image using HTML without JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote the following code:

```
<div class="slider-button-next slider-btn"> &lt; </div>
<img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" data-position="center center" />
<div class="slider-button-prev slider-btn"> &gt; </div>
```

I want the users to click on the left/right buttons in order to switch between images. Currently I have only one image `pic02.jpg`. How can I change the image displayed, without JS? (For example, changing to `pic03.jpg` when pressing right and changing to `pic01.jpg` when pressing left and so on). I'm planning to use hosting services to host my static website so as I understand, I can't use JS.

Comment: If you make this with JS that wont count as Dynamic, you can continue with JS

Comment: If you can load HTML, you can always use JS. as client side

Comment: @owenizedd No, you cannot depend on JS always being available: Every web-browser lets users disable JS (even Safari on iOS). JS is disabled by default in many privacy-centric browsers (e.g. Tor). Text-mode browsers like Lynx don't support JS at all, and many web-crawlers are HTML-only too.

Comment: any reason? No js, then impossible to change the src attribute.       

  Edit: since you mention all these browsers, the concern is the OP is thinking static hosting can't have JS loaded.

Comment: I thought that static hosting = no JS. Isn't it true?

Comment: _"How can I change the image displayed, without JS?"_ - use CSS triggers.

Comment: false, static hosting can have JS. because JS can be part of HTML by using `<script>` tag. Thus, back to my original argument, if you can load HTML, you can always use JS

Comment: @owenizedd "if you can load HTML, you can always use JS" - no, you cannot "always" use JS. _le sigh_ I just explained why an hour ago.

Comment: @Dai sigh, clearly the context of my answer is static hosting :) were not handling user disabling JS here :)))) and the answer static hosting can load JS

Answer (score 1):

If you're careful about where you position your elements you can do this:

```css
#mycheckbox~.images img:first-child {
  display: none;
}

#mycheckbox:checked+.images img:last-child {
  display: none;
}

#mycheckbox:checked+.images img:first-child {
  display: unset;
}
```

```html
<input id='mycheckbox' type='checkbox'> Click me
<div class='images'>
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300'>
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/433/200/300'>
</div>
```

The [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo class is on it's way (it's not in Firefox yet - check [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) but it's coming) and this allows you lots of flexibilty:

```css
.images img:first-child {
  display: none;
}

body:has(#mycheckbox:checked) .images img:last-child {
  display: none;
}

body:has(#mycheckbox:checked) .images img:first-child {
  display: unset;
}
```

```html
<input id='mycheckbox' type='checkbox'> Click me
<p> Lots of content here</p>
<div class='images'>
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300'>
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/433/200/300'>
</div>
```

You'd have to look at your slider element to see how it's been rendered in the DOM to see if it's an underlying check box or other input and change the rules accordingly.